# How to access local files with chrome (--allow-access doesn't work)

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, localhost

I am running a python script for a webpage. The python script connects to localhost:5000. In a html I have some images that are in local storage I want to load.

I have set the file to src to `file:///path/to/file/some_image.jpg`

However I keep getting the error `Not allowed to load local resource`

I have tried to allow local access using:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files`

However I get the same error. I have tried restarting my computer, chrome and ran everything from admin but still no luck.

How can I run local files in chrome with localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you checked whether you have permission to access those files?

Maybe you can try to use selenium to control the chrome through python, below is a simple python code that you can check it out(Replace the google.com to your html file).

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#introduction

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--allow-file-access-from-files")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work, as my files are in local I shouldn't need permissions? The only thing restricting me should be chrome?

Comment: That's really werid. I have also created a local html with a local jpg to simulate that situation, but it works.  hmmm, maybe it has something to do with chrome. Or you can try to switch a different browser.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried every browser and it still isn't working. The issue stems from having to run a python script as well. Could it be my local storage not allowing chrome to access them? if it is how would i check that?